# No Save/Apply button on Jenkins pipeline configuration page

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The **Save/Apply** button is missing from Jenkins pipeline configuration page. There seems to be no other way to apply changes to the configuration settings. I am unable to find any useful answers or workarounds as well. I have tried several Javascript workarounds, reinstallation, uninstalled plugins that generated warnings, and stuff but nothing seems to be working. I am using Jenkins version 2.222.3 with BlueOcean.

It would be a great help if anyone can suggest a solution.

[image: Jenkins pipeline configuration page]

Answer (score 2):

Using the GitHub plugin, we have an organization folder that is scanned for any repositories that contain a Jenkinsfile. The configuration you are viewing is driven by a config.xml that is copied from the organization folder into each job that runs in a repo. So you want your changes to affect `jobs/my_organization/config.xml`, not `jobs/my_organization/jobs/my_repo/config.xml`.

In the UI this is accomplished by going up a level or two from the job or job run. There you will see the link change from "View Configuration" to "Configure".

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins Pipeline configuration is defined in Jenkins Pipeline (e.g. Jenkinsfile). To change your configuration, you need to edit your Jenkinsfile.

E.g. to change "Build periodically", here's an example of edit you need to do:

```
pipeline {
    triggers {
        cron('* * * * *') // run every minute
```

This is why the page you're looking at is called "View Configuration" — it is for viewing only.